# Which steps does "insserv" take to install an init(System-V) script?

Tags: init

I played around with a LSB init script under Debian Wheezy(`init` is from sysvinit package version 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) for learning purposes. My script is following:

```
# cat /etc/init.d/test-script
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          test
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: test script
# Description:       test script
### END INIT INFO

# always executes
touch /tmp/test-file

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script test"
    touch /tmp/test-file-start
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script test"
    touch /tmp/test-file-stop
    ;;
  restart)
    echo "Restarting script test"
    touch /tmp/test-file-restart
    ;;
  force-reload)
    echo "Force-reloading script test"
    touch /tmp/test-file-force-reload
    ;;
  status)
    echo "Status of test"
    touch /tmp/test-file-status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/test {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0

#
```

I made the `/etc/init.d/test-script` file executable and added a symlink to `/etc/rc2.d/` directory:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov  2 13:19 /etc/rc2.d/S04test-script -> ../init.d/test-script
```

..as my default runlevel is 2 and reloaded the machine, but script was not started. As a final step I also added `test` to `/etc/init.d/.depend.start` file, but `/etc/init.d/test-script` was still not executed during a bootup.

Which additional steps does `insserv` take to install an init script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to symlinks to `/etc/rc<runlevel>.d/` directories, `insserv` adds a `<script_name>:` line to `/etc/init.d/.depend.start` file. My mistake was that I added `<boot_facility>:` line to `/etc/init.d/.depend.start` file. If we take the `/etc/init.d/test-script` as an example which has following LSB header:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          test
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: test script
# Description:       test script
### END INIT INFO
```

..then one needs to add `test-script:` line to `/etc/init.d/.depend.start` not the `test:` line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `update-rc.d` to setup the start and the stop for best results...
https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian

From insserver's man page:

It is not recommended to execute insserv directly unless you  know  exactly  what you're  doing,  doing  so  may  render  your  boot  system  inoperable.      update-rc.d is the recommended interface  for  managing  init  scripts.

Comment: I am aware of this, but I would like to understand how `insserv` works and what does it do.

Comment: @Martin Ok, I understand. Maybe you miss to call  **insserv test-script** ? You can check if the service is configured using **chkconfig --list | grep test-script**

Comment: I would like to understand what this `insserv test-script` command exactly does besides calculating the dependencies between the `init` scripts and creating corresponding symlinks to `/etc/rc<runlevel>` directories based on the LSB header in `init` scripts.

Comment: nothing more than what you have written. In accordance with the directives it configures the system to handle the startup and the shutdown of the service, via the script. I think you have already seen this link https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: If the `insserv` doesn't do nothing more what I have written in my initial post, then why doesn't the `/etc/init.d/test-script` create the `/tmp/test-file` and `/tmp/test-file-start` files when the system boots into runlevel 2?

Comment: I think that insserv calculate the correct start order of script. You writed **Required-Start:    $all**  so your test-script has to be starter after all other script. Maybe the link S04test-script is not the last one... I'm assuming this.

Comment: LilloX, good idea, but finally turned out, that I missed a simple step- I had to add `test-script:` line to `/etc/init.d/.depend.start`.